# Kubuntu 18.10 installed on M.2 drive, want to install Windows 10 on a secondary hard drive

Tags: system-installation, windows, kubuntu, 18.10

On my main system, I have Kubuntu 18.10 installed on an M.2 drive, I would like to install Windows 10 Pro on an Extra Sata Hard Drive without touching my Kubuntu install if at all possible, I would prefer not to remove my M.2 drive to install Windows because the drive is located behind the video card on the motherboard.

Comment: Many new systems have a setting in UEFI to turn off or disable a drive so not seen. I would do that if possible. Otherwise make sure UEFI default boot is to SATA drive not NVMe drive. Windows may put its boot partition on NVMe drive if seen as default boot and just overwrite the start of drive as it does not see Linux partitions. If UEFI, it may just use that ESP, so then probably not an issue. Be sure to install in same boot mode as Kubuntu, UEFI or BIOS. And install mode isdetermined by how you boot install media. But have good backups including ESP.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Actually, the ability to turn off or make the M.2 drive hidden might even work better for me, I have a case where the hard drives are docked in trays, I only want to fool with windows for some games I want to play and nothing else, I use Kubuntu for everything else and wasn't sure if I could disable the M.2 drive "on the fly" when I want to play with windows. This is a recent build with an MSI MATE B350 motherboard so I'm pretty sure that I can do just that. Thanks for the Help!